# STM32F407 - how do I run one motor at a time? Why do they ignore delays..?

Tags: stm32, pwm, timer, stepper-motor, stm32f407

I'm a newbie. I'm using an STM32F407 discovery board, and I want to control 6 stepper motors using PWM, especially OPM(One Pulse Mode).

Till now I've made 3 stepper motors work using Timer 8 (CH1, CH3, CH4).

What I intend to do is to make one motor work at a time. But they actually works together, even if I put 2 seconds of delay between motor control functions.

Is there something I can do to make one motor work at a time depending on a variable?(in this case, int k) And I don't know why It ignore delay and work together.

Here's the codes.

This is timer config generated by cubeMX

```
MX_TIM8_Init();
```

and the definition code.

```
static void MX_TIM8_Init(void)
{

  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig;
  TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC;
  TIM_BreakDeadTimeConfigTypeDef sBreakDeadTimeConfig;

  htim8.Instance = TIM8;
  htim8.Init.Prescaler = 672-1;
  htim8.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim8.Init.Period = 1000-1;
  htim8.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim8.Init.RepetitionCounter = 1;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_Init(&htim8) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  if (HAL_TIM_OnePulse_Init(&htim8, TIM_OPMODE_SINGLE) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim8, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_PWM1;
  sConfigOC.Pulse = 1;
  sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCNPolarity = TIM_OCNPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
  sConfigOC.OCIdleState = TIM_OCIDLESTATE_RESET;
  sConfigOC.OCNIdleState = TIM_OCNIDLESTATE_RESET;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim8, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim8, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim8, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_4) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.OffStateRunMode = TIM_OSSR_DISABLE;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.OffStateIDLEMode = TIM_OSSI_DISABLE;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.LockLevel = TIM_LOCKLEVEL_OFF;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.DeadTime = 0;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.BreakState = TIM_BREAK_DISABLE;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.BreakPolarity = TIM_BREAKPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.AutomaticOutput = TIM_AUTOMATICOUTPUT_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_ConfigBreakDeadTime(&htim8, &sBreakDeadTimeConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(&htim8);

}


void SPIN_C6_S (void) {

    for(int i =0;i<25;i++){
        HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim8, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
        HAL_Delay(10); 
    }
    k++;

}

void SPIN_C8_S (void) {

    for(int i =0;i<25;i++){
        HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim8, TIM_CHANNEL_3);
        HAL_Delay(10); 
    }
    k++;

}

void SPIN_C9_S (void) {

    for(int i =0;i<25;i++){
        HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim8, TIM_CHANNEL_4);
        HAL_Delay(10); 
    }
    k++;
}
```

This is variable and functions for motor control.

```
int k=0;

void SPIN_E9_S (void) { 

    for(int i =0;i<50;i++){
        HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
        HAL_Delay(10); 
    }
    k++;
}

void SPIN_E11_S (void) { 

    for(int i =0;i<50;i++){
        HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_2);
        HAL_Delay(10); 
    }
    k++;
}

void SPIN_E13_S (void) {

    for(int i =0;i<50;i++){
        HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_3);
        HAL_Delay(10); 
    }
    k++;
}
```

And This is the main().

```
int main(void) {

  HAL_Init();

  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_I2C1_Init();
  MX_I2S3_Init();
  MX_SPI1_Init();
  MX_USB_HOST_Init();
  MX_TIM8_Init();
  MX_TIM1_Init();

  while (1) {
    if(k%3==0){
        HAL_Delay(1000);
        SPIN_C6_S();
    }else if(k%3==1){
        HAL_Delay(1000);
        SPIN_C8_S();
    }else if(k%3==2){
        HAL_Delay(1000);
        SPIN_C9_S();
    }

    MX_USB_HOST_Process();
  }
}
```

All the codes are in main.c

Comment: Hi, mappy. Please fix your code indentation. Closing braces `}` should be inline with the first letter of the opening keyword, '**v**oid', '**f**or', etc. Decide on a standard for the opening brace `{` - either on the same line as the keyword (the normal way) or on a new line - and then stick to that convention. Inconsistencies at this level will make it difficult to understand and debug your program. You also have blank lines inside each of the for loops for no apparent reason. You should get into the habit of commenting your code. It will help you when you return to the project and others.

Comment: Why do you use pwm start inside a loop? Is enough just one before the "for" loop. Also, was missing a pwm stop (else the motor continue spinning).

Comment: Please show your timer configuration code as well.

Comment: @Transistor I agree with you. That's really important point. So I edited as you said. Thanks you!

Comment: @Direcu oh. I think I don't understand exactly how pwm works. I used pwm start inside a loop to give 25 pulse .. that's what I thought. But as you said, it need a pwm stop function. The function block would be like, Start - 'tell compiler what's the number' - stop.  

Then how can I control the number of pulse when I use start and stop function ?  

( And, Yes. They continue spinning. I didn't even know why. Your point would solve my problem..! )

Comment: @ajb I added it! But I don't know if I did it properly.

Comment: What kind of steppers? Bipolar or unipolar? What controller are you using for them? I've only ever used a stepper by walking thru the full-step or half-step sequence. Making one run on a PWM signal doesn't make sense to me unless you're using some daughter board to control them?